# How to find out in which Chromium version a commit was shipped

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

For example I need to know when [this commit](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/1979258), that resolved [this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=501582), was released to be able to support newer and older Chrome versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chromium's current version is specified in this file: `chrome/VERSION` So you will have to look at that file, to find out in which version that commit is present. For example, the link you have posted points to commit id: `277a0c8` which can be seen in that page and if you click that commit id which points to: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/277a0c817996a9ea0617a410d356d57e1cf8d548

So in your case if you look at this file: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/277a0c817996a9ea0617a410d356d57e1cf8d548/chrome/VERSION, that commit was merged in Chromium version `81.0.4035.0`

Hope that helps

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to use the [Chromium Dash service](https://chromiumdash.appspot.com/home):

https://chromiumdash.appspot.com/commits?commit=277a0c817996a9ea0617a410d356d57e1cf8d548&platform=Linux

[image]